# Why isn't httpd working?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssh, httpd, litespeed

I have just uninstalled Litespeed with the code below, but am getting an error when I try to start Apache through httpd. What can I do?

Here's the commands I used:

```
root@s15430558 [~]# /usr/local/lsws/admin/misc/uninstall.sh

WARNING: 

All sub directories under "/usr/local/lsws" 
created during installation will be removed! 
However, conf/ and logs/ can be optionally preserved. 
If you want to preserve any file under the other sub-directories created 
by installation script, please backup before proceeding.

Manually created sub-directories under "/usr/local/lsws" 
will not be touched.

Do you want to uninstall LiteSpeed Web Server? [y/N] y

Uninstalling rc scripts ...
[OK] The startup script has been successfully uninstalled!

Do you want to keep server configuration files? [y/N] y

Do you want to keep server log files? [y/N] n

LiteSpeed Web Server has been successfully uninstalled.

root@s15430558 [~]# service httpd restart
/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd: line 17: /usr/local/lsws/logs/ap_cmd_param.log: No such file or directory
/usr/local/apache/bin/httpd: line 52: /usr/local/lsws/bin/lswsctrl: No such file or directory
root@s15430558 [~]# ??
```

Greatly appreciate some help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Because file `/usr/local/lsws/logs/ap_cmd_param.log` mentioned in 17 line of apache config and `/usr/local/lsws/bin/lswsctrl` mentioned in 52 line of config do not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
cp /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd_ls_bak /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd
```

Answer (score 1):

In the /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd, it's calling some control and/or logging files that are in the lsws directories - you'll need to take a look at /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try looking in /etc/init.d/httpd and see what the "Start" case actually does. It might be starting the wrong httpd file...